# What are different options to deliver docker images

Tags: docker

I am exploring different options for deliver docker images. I see currently two options

1. Docker Hub, public or private repository
2. Docker save and export command feature

are there any other options Docker provides or any recommendations ?

Comment: you can also deliver the Dockerfiles and the necessary stuff, and build locally

Answer (score 1):

The list includes:

1. Docker Hub: public and private repo
2. Docker Trusted Registry: http://docs.docker.com/docker-trusted-registry/
3. Docker save and export
4. If multiple docker clients connect to the same daemon, images are shared among the clients.